# Enable Fusion logs Azure Web Job

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azure-web-app-service

I've a problem with an Azure Web Job, it runs locally, but it does not run on Azure. The problem is due to:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or 
assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The located 
assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. 
(Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040) at 
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ConverterManager..ctor()nat 
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.JobHostConfiguration..ctor(String 
dashboardAndStorageConnectionString)
```

I've installed `Newtonsoft 10.0.0` (this version is required by some libraries) and set up the assembly redirect in the app.config but it's not working.

Do you know how to enable Fusion on an Azure Web Job? Or how to investigate this kind of problems?

Thanks!

Comment: In your error message, the version is 9.0, but you say you have installed version 10.0. Could you provide more details.

Comment: show your code !

Comment: @JanleyZhang yeah it seems like the binding is not working properly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have installed the Newtonsoft.Json 10.0.x package, the version for Newtonsoft.Json under your project reference property would be 10.0.0. Based on your error, I assumed that the `dependentAssembly` may looks like as follows in your App.config file:

```
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-9.0.0.0" newVersion="10.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
```

You also need to check your bin folder and make sure the Product version property under the Details tab within the properties window of `Newtonsoft.Json.dll` is 10.0.x.x.

Moreover, you could try to explicitly handle the `AssemblyResolve` event under your Main(string[] args) method as follows:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += (sender, eventArgs) =>{
    //eventArgs.Name -> Newtonsoft.Json, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed
    var assemblyname = eventArgs.Name.Split(',').FirstOrDefault();
    if (assemblyname.Equals("Newtonsoft.Json", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        return System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(assemblyname);

        //or just load assembly from another folder
        /*
         * string path = @"c:\temp\";
         * return System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile(System.IO.Path.Combine(path, $"{assemblyname}.dll"));
         */
    }
    return null;
};
```

> I've a problem with an Azure Web Job, it runs locally, but it does not run on Azure.

You could leverage [KUDU](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2014/03/24/using-kudu-with-windows-azure-web-sites/) or [FTP](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaushal/2014/08/01/microsoft-azure-web-site-connect-to-your-site-via-ftp-and-uploaddownload-files/) to empty your Web Job content files, then redeploy your WebJob to narrow down this issue. If the above trials could not solve your issue, you'd better provide the `packages.config` in your Web Job project for us to troubleshoot this issue.